# How to plot n-th degree equation in pylab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm a new use of pylab of python. I want to plot a little complex equations by pylab like below.

```
f = 2x + 3y = 0
g = x^2 + 3y^2 - 3 = 0
h = sqrt(y) + 2x^2 = 0
```

I could plot some simple function defined by y = (something). But like upper equations, how should I plot f, g and h? Should I deform all equations to y = (...)?

Comment: `^` does not raise to the power in python, use `**` instead. In python `2**10` gives you 1024.

Comment: I don't understand the f=f(x,y) equal to 'zero' thing. Is f , g and h always equal to zero for any arbitrary combination of x and y? If so, you can always write the equation in terms of y. But then, there is no meaning of plotting f,g or h because they are constants with zero value. Please make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand both x and y are variables. These are the independent variables . And f,g and h are the dependent variables which are functions of x and y. In order to plot these functions you need three coordinate axes, i.e. you will have to draw a 3D graph. A code snippet is given below:

```
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
ax = Axes3D(figure())
x = arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = arange(0, 10, 0.1)
xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)
h = (yy)**0.5 + 2*(xx)**2.0
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, h , cmap=cm.jet, cstride=1)
show()
```

The output will be like this:
[image: Output]

Or you can plot a 2D heatmap. Like as follows:

```
from pylab import *
x = arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = arange(0, 10, 0.1)
xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)
f = 2*(xx) + 3*(yy)
imshow(f)
show()
```

Here the output looks like this:
[image]